# Is there a way to insert raw javascript in parenscript code?

Tags: common-lisp, parenscript

The following code inserts third-party generated javascript as a string which will need to be eval'ed.

```
(ps (let ((x (lisp (json:encode-json-alist-to-string
                 '((:a . 1) (:b . 2))))))))

"(function () {
   var x = '{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}';
    return null; })();"
```

Is there a way to tell parenscript to insert a string unquoted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Added this to parenscript's non-cl.lisp file:

```
(define-expression-operator lisp-raw (lisp-form)
  `(ps-js:escape
    ,lisp-form))

(defun lisp-raw (x) x)
```

Result:

```
(ps (let ((x (ps::lisp-raw (json:encode-json-alist-to-string
                 '((:a . 1) (:b . 2))))))))
"(function () {
    var x = {\"a\":1,\"b\":2};
    return null;
})();"
```